# Error: Clipboard on X11 requires 'xclip' (recommended) or 'xsel'

Tags: r, reprex

I'm trying to extract part of a very large dataset, I used the datapasta function:

`tribble_format(head(dataframe, 32))`

and I got this error: Error: Clipboard on X11 requires 'xclip' (recommended) or 'xsel'
How am I supposed to fix it?

Answer (score 0):

`xclip` and `xsel` are two different command-line utilities for managing the X11 clipboard.  It sounds like your library is using these to interface with that clipboard.  If you can, use your Linux distribution's standard package manager to install one or both of these.

For example, with a Debian-like distribution:

```
sudo apt install xclip xsel
```